# Flatten nested pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

After some aggregation, my dataframe looks something like this

```
  A     B
        B_min   B_max
0 11     3       6       
1 22     1       2
2 33     4       4
```

How do I make the columns be `A`, `B_min` and `B_max`, without any nesting? Simple and standard. I've tried `reindex_axix()` and `unstack()`, but nothing worked.

Comment: What is the code create this df ? What knid of method you are using ? Maybe fix it at the beginning is better than modify the result

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in my hands, but if you can tell me how to change the groupby statement, I can check with the responsible person...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, but I wish there was an in-built way to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 11, 22, 22, 33, 33],
                   'B': [3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 4]})

g = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg({'B': ['min', 'max']})

g.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() if col[1] else col[0] for col in g.columns.values]

#     A  B_min  B_max
# 0  11      3      6
# 1  22      1      2
# 2  33      4      4
```

Comment: That seems to mostly work, except that it adds a trailing underscore to the other columns that are not nested.

Comment: @BaronYugovich, see update. But I hope there's a better way.

Comment: Maybe, let's see if someone else proposes something different. If not, I will select your answer in a day or so.

Comment: this is actually a fairly common use case IMHO and it is easily done in `R` as there's a built-in function that does this. Pandas, for some peculiar reason, just don't seem to see the use case and it took me quite some time to get to your answer whilst I know I was looking for something that should've been fairly simple.